# QGraphicsItem::itemChange notified for position change but not for size change

Tags: qt

I've got a class derived from QGraphicsEllipseItem in which I need to know when its position or size changes in any way.  I handle resizing with a mouse and calls to QGraphicsEllipse::setRect.

OK, so I dutifully overrode the itemChange() method in the class and then was careful to set the ItemSendsGeometryChanges flag after creating it

```
// Returns a human readable string for any GraphicsItemChange enum value

inline std::string EnumName(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemChange e);

// Simple test ellipse class

class MyEllipse : public QGraphicsEllipseItem
{
public:
    MyEllipse(int x, int y, int w, int h) : QGraphicsEllipseItem(x, y, w, h)
    {
        setFlags(
            QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable 
            | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable 
            | QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
    }


    // QGraphicItem overrides
    virtual QVariant itemChange(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value) override
    {
        std::stringstream oss;
        oss << "ItemChange " << EnumName(change) << std::endl;
        OutputDebugString(oss.str().c_str());
        return __super::itemChange(change, value);
    }
};
```

My main code creates one of these, adds it to the scene and then tries moving/resizing it.

And while I do always receive notifications after calling setPos() on the ellipse, I get NO notification after calling setRect().  I can use setRect to completely change the ellipse's geometry but my itemChange override is never called.  Not with any flags.

Now obviously changing the item's rect is changing its geometry, so what am I missing?

Is there some other flag I should set?  Some other way to change the size of the ellipse I should use?  Some other notification virtual I can override?

Comment: At first, first 3 lines of your `itemChange` can be exchanged to `qDebug() << change;`... At second, what `QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemChange` value do you expect? Most close values are `ItemTransformChange` and `ItemScaleChange`, but they are related with a bit different thing. You can try to resize ellipse by `setTransform` method and should receive one of them.

Comment: I guess I expect there to be some value in GraphicsItemChange that covers this since it clearly is a changing of the item geometry and I specifically set the flag to be notified of changes to that geometry.  It seems to be a glaring gap in this notification if only the item's position is considered a part of its geometry.

I can move the ellipse to my heart's content but there doesn't seem to be any way to resize it and be notified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `QGraphicsItem`'s position is not related with `QGraphicsEllipseItem`'s rectangle. The first one is a position of the item relative to it's parent item or, if it is `NULL`, to it's scene. The last one is a rectangle relative **to the item position** where an ellipse should be drawn. The scene and `QGraphicsItem`'s core don't know about any changes of it.

Let's take a look at this test:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QGraphicsView view(&scene);
    QGraphicsEllipseItem item(10, 20, 30, 40);
    scene.addItem(&item);

    qDebug() << item.pos() << item.scenePos() << item.boundingRect();
    item.setRect(110, 120, 30, 40);
    qDebug() << item.pos() << item.scenePos() << item.boundingRect();

    view.resize(500, 500);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Output is:

```
QPointF(0,0) QPointF(0,0) QRectF(9.5,19.5 31x41)
QPointF(0,0) QPointF(0,0) QRectF(109.5,119.5 31x41)
```

Possible ways out:

1. use `setTransform`. Transform matrix changes are tracked by standard `QGraphicsitem`s, and `itemChange` will receive corresponding change. But I guess that non-ident matrices can decrease performance (didn't check).
2. implement your own function like `setRect` in which you will track geometry changes manually.
3. subclass `QGraphicsItem`, not `QGraphicsEllipseItem`. In this case you can prevent untrackable geometry changes as they are performed through your rules. It looks like this:

   ```
   class EllipseItem: public QGraphicsItem
   {
   public:
       // Here are constructors and a lot of standard things for
       // QGraphicsItem subclassing, see Qt Assistant.
       ...

       // This method is not related with QGraphicsEllipseItem at all.
       void setRect(const QRectF &newRect)
       {
           setPos(newRect.topLeft());
           _width = newRect.width();
           _height = newRect.height();
           update();
       }

       QRectF boundingRect() const override
       {
           return bRect();
       }

       void paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * option,
                  QWidget * widget = nullptr) override
       {
           painter->drawRect(bRect());
       }

   private:
       qreal   _width;
       qreal   _height;

       QRectF bRect() const
       {
           return QRectF(0, 0, _width, _height);
       }
   };
   ```

   You also should track item transformations and moves through `QGraphicsItem::itemChange`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It just doesn't seem to make any sense to me that I'm supposed to be able to be notified about changes to the items geometry and yet it is so easy to change that geometry without any way of being notified.

Comment: @Joe We have what we have. : ) One more way is to subclass `QGraphicsItem` and to implement such methods as you want. It is easy to implement own `setRect` and nobody will call "wrong" unnotifiable methods in this case.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I've done.  I guess it's the C++ purist/worrier in me.  QGraphicsEllipseItem::setRect is not virtual.  I don't know what goes on inside of QT.  Is it ever calling that function itself?  I hope not, or I'll have holes to plug...

Comment: Rather than subclassing QGraphicsEllipseItem (or QGraphicsRectItem and the other shape item classes), you may find that it's more practical to subclass QGraphicsItem. When I first started with these, I avoid creating my own because I didn't want to deal with the painting, but in the long run, it was far easier to create exactly what I wanted rather than try to work around the limitations of the built-in shape item classes. They're great for learning or if your needs are simple, but it's pretty easy to roll your own from scratch.